# openAm 12.0.0 failed to add user with external opendj

Tags: openam, opendj

I had build and install openam 12 from source code, from svn checkout
 link:

svn checkout https://svn.forgerock.org/openam/tags/12.0.0/openam/

after that I had used external OpenDJ-2.6.0 with openam , installation is successful.
 But when I add new user and click OK I got error

```
Error :”Plug-in org.forgerock.openam.idrepo.ldap.DJLDAPv3Repo encountered a ldap exception. ldap errorcode=65”
```

Also check in OpenDJ-2.6.0 logs access logs:

```
 [25/Feb/2015:16:27:00 +0530] ADD RES conn=6 op=131 msgID=132 result=65     message=”Entry uid=indranis,dc=xyz,dc=net violates the Directory Server schema configuration because it contains an unknown objectclass iPlanetPreferences” etime=2
```

Same exception I got when I try to add group ,
but able to solve referring following link:

https://java.net/projects/opensso/lists/users/archive/2007-08/message/21

remove manually from Data Store – opends and remove groupOfURLs or groupOfUniqueNames from the LDAP Groups Object Class

Is there is issue with openDJ2.6 version , or any changes do I need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got issue resolve, by installing openAM with embeded datastore and and then after installation ,configured it with an external opendj store and removed embedded one.

Comment: I belive it helps, but it is so ugggly.